# NVME M.2 SSD cant be formmated as ext4

Tags: linux

Ive been trying to fix this for about 2 months.
If i run mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p5
It results in:
https://pastebin.com/HeQLFijU
Someone Please Help!
This is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
~ >>> sudo fdisk -l                                                         [1]
[sudo] password for xsucculentx: 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD                       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C641908F-28F1-4E1D-99A7-35CBFFC00B9F

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3 203098112 499079820 295981709 141.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 499081216 500115455   1034240   505M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DE8DFD03-EDE8-5C4E-8170-B1BD412ED17E

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953525134 1953523087 931.5G Linux filesystem
```

EDIT: ok i left out a lot of information, so here we go: i recently got my m.2 ssd and put it in my pc and set it up with windows. it runs good with no problems, i have 2 drives in my pc, hdd with 1 tb and a ssd with 256gb the hdd formats with ext4 perfectly fine, the ssd either results in a kernal panic or just gives me a error, i wanted to dualboot windows and manjaro gnome on my ssd and have the hdd as my storage, but for some reason i am unable to do it.

Comment: Can you add the output of `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` into the question please (i.e. use `edit` and add the extra information)?

Comment: Ok! i added it.

Comment: And yes i deleted the partition 5 before i sent this

Comment: Thank you for the additional data. Unfortunately it doesn't enable me to help you. As you know it is reporting I/O errors for the 5th partition. Assuming that the partition took the remaining space on the device then the errors are well inside the device limits.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a filesystem on partition 5 when only four are defined in the partition table?

Comment: First only use Windows to shrink your NTFS partition & reboot Windows so it can run the required chkdsk after any resize. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. Then you can create new Linux partition and format it. I prefer gparted, but any Linux tool will work. Or just install into the allocated space.  Have you updated UEFI firmware and SSD firmware?

Comment: i have updated the post above with valuable info

Comment: @roaima: <del>I remember the question stating that partition 5 was removed later.  But I can't find that in any version of the question anymore.</del> Nope, it was a comment

Comment: Well now the information in the question is no longer self-consistent. It's highly unlikely anyone's going to be able to piece together the details given they don't even match. Put the missing partition back, show us the disk partition layout, and the corresponding errors (if any).

Comment: im going to zero the disk tonight and try to format it

Answer (score 0):

According to your log your SSD is already dead or dying.

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
or
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
```

will probably let you know why it's happening.

Comment: i literally just got it a few weeks ago and windows runs perfectly on it

Comment: i have not had the chance to get on my pc today, but i will run the commands when i do